# How to call Model Binding manually in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

Anybody know how to easily reuse the built in model binders in .Net Core?

I have to make a call to an api regularly that returns with NamedValuePaired data (like a querystring) Is there an easy way to just take reuse the  model binder instead of parsing the data?

I could just take the data and make another call to a controller of my own to do the binding but, there has to be way other than doing a http post to my own controller.

Currently I am doing the following:

```
var rawResponse = "";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    //Post to paypal
    var response = await client.PostAsync(_options.TokenUrl, new StringContent(parameters, Encoding.UTF8, "text/namevalue"));
    //read response
    rawResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
var nameValues = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(rawResponse);

Model m = new Model();

if (nameValues.ContainsKey("RESULT"))
    m.Result = Convert.ToByte(nameValues["RESULT"].FirstOrDefault());

// etc....
```

Ideally I'd like to take the response and pass it through a the built in model binder like it was being posted to me.

Comment: as a start point you may use MVC repo to find how to create instance of IModelBinder https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/ModelBinderFactory.cs